# Conditionally subtracting Pandas Dataframe rows based on row names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a large dataset, but the problem can be summarized using the smaller dataset below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Filename":["fileName1_uniqueTag1", "fileName2_uniqueTag1", "fileName3_uniqueTag1", "fileName1_uniqueTag2", "fileName2_uniqueTag2", "fileName3_uniqueTag2"], 
                   "measurement":[1336.564888, 1090.852579, 990.320323, 1202.522612, 1098.045258, 923.600277],})
print(df)
>>>
               Filename  measurement
0  fileName1_uniqueTag1  1336.564888
1  fileName2_uniqueTag1  1090.852579
2  fileName3_uniqueTag1   990.320323
3  fileName1_uniqueTag2  1202.522612
4  fileName2_uniqueTag2  1098.045258
5  fileName3_uniqueTag2   923.600277
```

There are three different file names with two unique tags for each file name in the "Filename" column. The goal is to calculate the ratio of the measurements for uniqueTag1/uniqueTag2 for each file. The result *should* look something like this:

```
    Filename  uniqueTag2/uniqueTag1
0  fileName1               0.899711
1  fileName2               1.006593
2  fileName3               0.932627
```

I can make lists of the three different file names and two different tags using:

```
nameList = df["Filename"].tolist()
fileNames = []                              #empty list to fill with different base file names
uniqueTags = []                             #empty list to fill with unique tags
for name in nameList:                       #iterate through list of full file names
    subStrings = name.split("_")            #splits each base file name at the underscore
    if subStrings[0] not in fileNames:      #if the base file name isn't already in the file names list...
        fileNames.append(subStrings[0])     #append it
    if subStrings[1] not in uniqueTags:     #if the unique tag isn't already in the unique tags list...
        uniqueTags.append(subStrings[1])    #append it
```

I think that I could access individual measurement values by making the Filenames into indexes and using df.at(), but this seems horribly messy and I'm certain there must be a much better way to do this using functionality within Pandas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, which is pretty straightforward, using [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['Filename','uniquetag']] = df['Filename'].str.split('_', expand=True)
tag1 = df.loc[df['uniquetag'] == 'uniqueTag1'].set_index('Filename')['measurement']
tag2 = df.loc[df['uniquetag'] == 'uniqueTag2'].set_index('Filename')['measurement']
tag2 / tag1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df[['one','two']] = df.filename.str.split("_",expand=True)
```

Then `groupby` using those 2 columns